# Append does not work with mousepressed?

Tags: arrays, append, processing

I am having an issue with my project, and cannot figure it out. Processing is telling me what I have is not an array, but I do not see how it is not. Also, this issue only occurs when I click the mouse in an attempt to make something else appear.

```
int numParticles = 200;

GenParticle [] p = new GenParticle[numParticles];

float r=170;
float g=150;
float b=85;
float velX;
float velY;

void setup(){
  size(500,500);
  noStroke();
  smooth();
  frameRate(30);
  for (int i=0; i<p.length; i++){
     velX = random(-1,1);
     velY = -i;
    p[i]=new GenParticle(width/2,height/2,velX,velY,5.0,width/2,height/2);
  }
}

void draw(){
  fill(0,20);
  rect(0,0,width,height);

  fill(255,60);
  for(int i=0; i<p.length; i++){
    p[i].update();
    p[i].regenerate();
    p[i].display();
  }
}

void mousePressed() { 
    GenParticle gp = new GenParticle(mouseX,mouseY, velX, velY,5.0,mouseX,mouseY);
    p = (GenParticle[]) append(gp,p);
}


class GenParticle extends Particle{
  float originX,originY;


  GenParticle(int xIn,int yIn,float vxIn,float vyIn,float r,float ox,float oy){
    super(xIn, yIn, vxIn, vyIn, r);
    originX=ox;
    originY=oy;
  }

  void regenerate(){
    if ((x>width+radius) || (x<-radius) || (y>height+radius) || (y<-radius)){
      x=originX;
      y=originY;
      vx=random(-1.0,1.0);
      vy=random(-4.0,-2.0);
    }
  }
}


class Particle{
  float x, y;
  float vx,vy;
  float radius;
  float gravity=0.1;
  float r=0;
  float g=0;
  float b=0;

  Particle(int xpos,int ypos,float velx,float vely,float r){
    x=xpos;
    y=ypos;
    vx=velx;
    vy=vely;
    radius=r;
  }

  void update(){
    vy=vy+gravity;
    y += vy;
    x += vx;
  }

  void display(){
    fill(r,g,b);
    ellipse(x, y, radius*3,radius*3);

  if(mouseX>width/2){
    r=r+9;
     }else{
      g=g+6;
     }

  if(mouseY>height/2){
    b=b+7;
     }else{
      b=b-3;
     }

  if(keyPressed) {
    g=g+1;
     }else{
      g=g-5;
     }

  r=constrain(r,0,255);
  g=constrain(g,0,255);
  b=constrain(b,0,255);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add a tag to indicate the language.

Comment: "Processing is an open source programming language and integrated development environment (IDE) built for the electronic arts, new media art, and visual design communities with the purpose of teaching the fundamentals of computer programming in a visual context, and to serve as the foundation for electronic sketchbooks. "

Comment: There is this article in processing wiki that might be of your interest. It's about append vs ArrayList.http://wiki.processing.org/w/Why_use_ArrayList_instead_of_array_with_append()%3F

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error: the array is the first parameter and the object you want to append is the second parameter of the [append()](http://processing.org/reference/append_.html) function

Your mousePressed should look like this:

```
void mousePressed() { 
    GenParticle gp = new GenParticle(mouseX,mouseY, velX, velY,5.0,mouseX,mouseY);
    p = (GenParticle[]) append(p,pg);
}
```

Notice the array `p` goes first, then the object (append to array p object pg).